# syncing Github with Pythonanywhere

Tags: git, github, pythonanywhere

I want to sync pythonanywhere project with github account.
Like If I make changes in my project at github,it automatically gets updated at pythonanywhere.
Forgive me I am new to github.

Answer (score 12):

I just solved this issue for my own Pythonanywhere project. I did not want to bother with SSH keys, so I used Github webhooks and a Python script that runs on my pythonanywhere account. The Python script listens to the webhook that Github emits when the source code has been updated and executes a script on pythonanywhere to pull in the new files.

Here is the scenario:

- I develop in Visual Studio on my local computer and push my code to my Github repository
- Github automatically emits a post-receive webhook with a json file that I listen to on my pythonanywhere server
- In my python script I simply execute a pull command as soon as the webhook URL gets triggered. After that all my files on pythonanyhwere are up-to-date

Tips:

- If you have not yet initiated git on your pythonanywhere project, just open a bash console, navigate to your root folder, e.g. "home/username" and enter `git init`, then `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/yourreponame.git`
- You can create the post-receive webhook in your github repository's settings page
- I use the GitPython package to execute the pull request
- Below is the python code I use in my flask web server to wait for the webhook to execute. It basically executes a predefined bash command that gets created automatically in your pythonanywhere file structure and that is located under `.git/hooks/`. This bash file will execute a simple `git pull origin master`

### The content of my flask_app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import git

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
    def webhook():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            repo = git.Repo('./myproject')
            origin = repo.remotes.origin
            repo.create_head('master', 
        origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master).checkout()
            origin.pull()
            return '', 200
        else:
            return '', 400

#
# Below here follows you python back-end code
#
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Wanni would you mind including all import statements to your function above? 'import git' is clear, but where does 'request' and 'app' come from?

Comment: Can this exist in the same webapp that is supposed to update?

Comment: @aadibajpai yes, the piece of python code above is located in the same file (flask_app.py) that runs my flask server/back-end.

Comment: @Wanni how does it reload?

Comment: Okay, I looked into it—if you add a post-merge hook to touch the wsgi file then the webapp will reload if the pull goes successful :)

Answer (score 4):

You could consider:

- developing locally (See [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/) to create an account, a new repo, and clone it locally)
- pushing and updating your repo/app on [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), as described in "[Git push deployments on PythonAnywhere](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/87/)"

If you want to develop only on pythonanywhere, you would need to generate an SSH key, and add the public one to your GitHub account, as suggested in "[How to get your code in and out of PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/FTP/)".

Comment: What would I need to do after I add the SSH key to GitHub? Is the idea that GitHub updates from PA?

Comment: @aadibajpai Yes, you could push from PA to GitHub.

Comment: that wouldn't be automated though as mentioned in OP's question.

Comment: @aadibajpai I suppose not, but the question is about automating the propagation of GitHub changes to PA, not the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

For **Django**:

first you need to install gitpython: `pip install gitpython`

update `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from git import Repo # 
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        repo = Repo('./django-schools')
        git = repo.git
        git.checkout('master')
        git.pull()
        return HttpResponse('pulled_success')
    return HttpResponse('get_request', status=400)
```

Comment: This is the closest solution I found, however, I'm getting the following error: "git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
cmdline: git checkout master
stderr: 'fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree' ". After looking into this it seems the solution is "Create another repository elsewhere, add a file in that repository and, push it to the bare repository." It makes little sense as to why I need to create another repository.