# git webhook fails - do you know why?

Tags: python, git, webhooks, continuous-deployment, pythonanywhere

**Background:**

I have a [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview) repo called `DOSTUFF` that includes a python script `do_stuff.py`. I edit it using [Eclipse pydev](http://www.pydev.org/) on my local machine and push changes to bitbucket via `git push origin master`.

I cloned `DOSTUFF` to a [pythonanywhere](http://pythonanywhere.com) trial account without any issues.

Now, whenever I edit `do_stuff.py` locally and then `git commit -m 'foo'` & `git push origin master` them to bitbucket, I manually need to `git pull` from within pythonanywhere afterwards in order to see the edits in pythonanywhere. This [is inefficient](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sucks%20ass&amp=true&defid=1422723).

**Objectives:**

I want that my local (Eclipse) commits to bitbucket get pulled automatically to pythonanywhere once pushed from local to bitbucket. Apparently, [webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) are the way to go.

**Challenges:**

In order to do so, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047123/syncing-github-with-pythonanywhere) hint by specifying a webhook within bitbucket to `pythonanywhere/user/me/webhook.py`. Unfortunately, those instructions are minimalistic as they lack proper imports and don't elucidate as to why flask is necessary (I am not an expert).

`webhook.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

import git
from flask import Flask, request

# Initiate flask instance
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        repo = git.Repo('./DOSTUFF')
        origin = repo.remotes.origin
        repo.create_head('master',
    origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master).checkout()
        origin.pull()
        return '', 200
    else:
        return '', 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Now, when I `git push` from Eclipse to bitbucket, the commit(s) arrive at bitbucket but the code in pythonanywhere remains unchanged. In other words, `webhook.py` fails.

In contrast, when I run `webhook.py` from within pythonanywhere (bash console), I yield the following error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ME/webhook.py", line 21, in <module>
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 795, in run_simple
    s.bind(get_sockaddr(hostname, port, address_family))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

**Questions:**

**What's the root cause for this to fail?**

**How to properly configure a webhook that is necessary and sufficient to auto-`git pull` changes to pythonanywhere once pushed from local to bitbucket?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to start a server in a PythonAnywhere console, which will not work since traffic is not routed to console servers. Use a web app to create the server to listen for the web hooks.